# in React, how do i toggle only 1 element to render at a time onClick in React and hide the others until clicked?

Tags: reactjs, toggle

when an image is clicked, i have it rotating and toggling an Answer to a Question, but ALL Q/A pairs show all or none onClick. How do i make ONLY the clicked one show the answer, one at a time?

```
function FAQs() {    
    function useToggle(initialState = false) {
        const [toggleValue, setToggleValue] = useState(true);
        const toggler = () => {
          setToggleValue(!toggleValue);
        };
        return [toggleValue, toggler];
      }
    const [toggle, setToggle] = useToggle();

    const [rotateArrow, setRotateArrow] = useState(false);
    const handleRotate = () => setRotateArrow(!rotateArrow);
    const rotate = rotateArrow ? "rotate(90deg)" : "rotate(0)"
```

return (

```
          <Question>First question goes here </Question>
          <ArrowRight onClick={() => { handleRotate();setToggle();}} style={{ transform: rotate }}></ArrowRight>

          {toggle && <Answer><p>"Question 1 Answer, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat zzril delenit augue duis dolore te feugait nulla facilisi."</p></Answer>
           }
```

//Second Question will ALSO toggle onClick when question 1 is clicked, not independently.

```
      <Question>Second question goes here </Question>
      <ArrowRight onClick={() => { handleRotate();setToggle();}} style={{ transform: rotate }}></ArrowRight>

      {toggle && <Answer><p>"Question 2 Answer, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat zzril delenit augue duis dolore te feugait nulla facilisi."</p></Answer>
       }
```

Comment: Have more than one boolean shared between them all?

Answer (score 1):

the same toggle state is used for both questions, causing both answers to show at the same time.you should create a component for each question and use a unique state for each question's toggle.

create a QuestionToggle component that will contain the individual state and behavior for each question

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';

const QuestionToggle = ({ question, answer }) => {
    const [toggle, setToggle] = useState(false);

    return (
        <div>
            <div>
                <p>{question}</p>
                <button onClick={() => setToggle(!toggle)}>
                    <img className='arrow-right' src={""} />
                </button>
            </div>
            {toggle && <div>{answer}</div>}
        </div>
    );
};
```

use this component in your main component for each question and answer

```
    <div>
            <QuestionToggle
                question="First question goes here"
                answer={ /* answer here */}
            />
           <QuestionToggle
                question="Second question goes here"
                answer={ /* answer here */}
            />
            {/* Add more QuestionToggle components for other questions and answers */}
        </div>
```